# Nested classes with EMF/ecore

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-emf, emf, eclipse-emf-ecore, ecore

The ecore model editor does not allow adding classes as children to classes; doing so manually as in

```
...
<eClassifiers xsi:type="ecore:EClass" name="Test_Class">
    <eClassifiers xsi:type="ecore:EClass" name="Nested_Class"></eClassifiers>
    ...
```

results in

```
org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.FeatureNotFoundException: Feature 'eClassifiers' not found. (platform:/resource/EMFTestProject/model/My.ecore, 5, 62)
```

Is there any way to model something like nested classes in ecore files?

Comment: You mean that you wanna create a containment relation between two classes ?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot create nested `EClasses` in Ecore. The only elements that can be contained by `EClass` are `EStructuralFeatures` (references and attributes), `EOperation`, `EAnnotation`, `EGenericType` and `ETypeParameter`.

Take a look to the Ecore metamodel:
http://download.eclipse.org/modeling/emf/emf/javadoc/2.10.0/org/eclipse/emf/ecore/package-summary.html

Answer (score 0):

For creating a containment reference between two EClass objects in a metamodel you have to create A `EReference ereference=EcoreFactory.eInstance.create` and add is the the mother class : `motherclass.getEReferences().add(ereference)`
and put the children class as EType of the ereference. `ereference.setEType()`